# Why the iframe from youtube is visilbe in Firefox and IE when using backdrop in Bootstrap modals?

Tags: internet-explorer, firefox, iframe, twitter-bootstrap, modal-dialog

I have problem with Bootstrap modals which I show you in screens.

Here is what I want and what I see in Chrome:

[image]

And here is result in Firefox:

[image]

and in IE:

[image]

I didn't change any css in iframes,Bootstrap modal is standard.

How can I fix it ?

Answer (score 0):

Answer:

```
 <iframe class="video" width="100%" height="315" src="http://www.youtube.com/embed/m6Xp0OxHNBI?wmode=transparent" frameborder="0" allowfullscreen=""></iframe>

  ?wmode=transparent
```